# how to update email in firebase authentication i wrote a code which update- email in realtime database but not updating in Authentication

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I wrote a code for updating in authentication and realtime database, but not updating in authentication.
What to do for the authentication updating?
How to update the email in the authentication also along with realtime database?

How to implement this kindly guide to achieve the output?

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityUpdateBinding
private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityUpdateBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    dbRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")

    binding.btnUpdate.setOnClickListener {

        val name = binding.etName.text.toString()
        val password = binding.etPassword.text.toString()
        val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString()

        updateData(name,password,email)

fun updateData(name: String, password: String, email: String) {

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")

    val user = mapOf<String,String>(
        "name" to name,
        "password" to password,
        "email" to email

    )
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("currentEmail","currentPassword")
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success now update email
                firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            // email update completed
                        }else{
                            // email update failed
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                // sign in failed
            }
        }
    dbRef.child(name).updateChildren(user).addOnSuccessListener {
        binding.etName.text.clear()
        binding.etPassword.text.clear()
        binding.etEmail.text.clear()

        Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Failed to update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly happen when you're using this code?

Comment: it is updating the email in the firebase realtime database but not updating in authentication

Comment: Have you tried to log the result if the task is not successful?

Comment: yes it not giving the output in log

Comment: How did you do that? There are only empty statements.

Comment: can you please help me out with solution

Comment: Your code looks fine, but most likely it fails with an exception that you don't know about since you aren't checking that.

Comment: This call in your code should update the email of the user on the server: `firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(email)`. If that is not working, you'll need to check the `task` in the callback for that call to see if there an error and (if so) log that.